# How to collect sensor data in Rust and make it queryable/available in Python?

Tags: python, rust

How to use Rust to collect a time series/stream of sensor data and then make this data available from Python (whilst Rust continues to collect data)?

The objective would be for Rust to continue collecting the data and allow for Python to call functions which would allow to query/retrieve this data. For example all the observations over the past 5 minutes.

Is this possible to achieve without copying memory (similar to view of numpy arrays) or does memory have to be copied when it is received in the Python runtime?

If memory needs to be copied how does the runtime cost of doing it in Rust compare to a doing it in C? Would C be simpler/easier to implement when compared to Rust (as a novice C programmer I like the safety/tools Rust offers)?

In summary, I would like to understand how to:

- Collect sensor data and continue to collect it in Rust in the background
- Allow the data collected in Rust to be queried from Python
- Does the data need to be copied when queried from Python or can memory views similar to numpy be implemented?
- If the data needs to be copied how does the overhead compare to C?
- How does the complexity of implementing this is Rust compare to C?

Comment: Why just not use Rust to save in a database and Python to read from the database ?

Comment: *Would C be simpler/easier to implement when compared to Rust*: definitely not.

Comment: Are you writing a (C API) extension for Python in Rust? Or embedding Python in Rust? If so, you can use the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) to expose an object that shares a buffer (presumably immutably) with a Python object, and then your Python code can iterate that, create a `memoryview` over it, construct an `np.array` out of it, etc. without copying. There are definitely advantages to writing C extensions in C rather than Rust—but also some advantages to writing them in Rust. (The macros wrap up a _lot_ of boilerplate…)

Comment: If these are entirely separate processes, then I assume you'd be using shared memory or an `mmap`, in which case… yeah, of course that can be zero-copy. But if you want to wrap things up in some way where there's a pipe that you use to pass metadata about the shared memory… well, that's not _hard_ work, but it's a pretty good amount of easy work.

Comment: This question is *way* too broad.

Comment: Finally, going back to extending or embedding… you can access the numpy C API from Rust. And, while it's not _quite_ as convenient to use a numpy buffer as a native Rust array, it doesn't sound like you're doing all that much complicated stuff with those arrays on the Rust side.

Comment: Oh, and as for the runtime cost  of a copy: copying a big hunk of memory comes down to a call to the platform's `memmove`. Of course you could write an equivalent loop in explicit C or Rust or assembly, but it's not going to be better than the platform stdlib (which is what you'll get from calling `memmove` in C, or `buf2 = buf[:]` in Python, etc.).

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for commenting in so much detail - it is very helpful! I am starting from a clean slate so it's excellent to understand what options are available. I now have a list of possible solutions which I can look into further and understand. Thank you! P.s. If you post the comments as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is to vague to be answered correctly, let me suggest you some approaches.

## 1. Using an intermediate layer

You can use some sort of database (e.g. sqlite, postgresql, ...), filesystem storage (plain text file, sockets) or even build a Webserver with a (JSON) API.

Depending on what you want to use, there are crates for everything (plain text is in std, sqlite, postgres, diesel, hyper, serde, etc).

The neat thing about this implementation is, that it is programming language indepenent, if you for example decide to reprogram your code in Java later (for whatever reason :) ), you just have to change the way java reads the code out of the database/socket/webserver.

## 2. Using FFI

You can take a look at the example from alex at [github.com](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples/tree/master/python-to-rust), but be aware of the types you can use in FFI, e.g. integer types like i32, u32, i8, pointer, floatings but things like strings can get very hairy, so if you are fine with integer only, use that.